# Simplifying Trigonometric Recursive functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that:
 $$p_k=k\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)\quad\quad\quad P_k=k\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)$$
How can I show that $$P_{2k}=\frac{2p_kP_k}{p_k+P_k}\quad\quad\quad p_{2k}=\sqrt{p_kP_{2k}}$$

I started off by doing this: $$\frac{2p_kP_k}{p_k+P_k}=\frac{2\left[k\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)\right]\left[k\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)\right]}{\left[k\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)\right]+\left[k\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)\right]}$$
but this is way to complicated and there must be a shorter approach.

Comment: @Winther Yes that's what I meant

Comment: If you write $x= \frac{\pi}{2k}$ then $p_{2k}^2 = p_k P_{2k}$ just says that $4\sin^2(x) = 2\sin(2x)\tan(x)$ which is true for all $x$ (use $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ to see this). By taking the square root you need to be sure that $p_{2k}$ is positive (which it is for all $k$).

Comment: @Winther Ok. I understand. How about the first one?

Comment: The first formula can be proven similary by recalling the formula for $\tan(x/2)$ in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ (here with $x= \frac{\pi}{k}$).

Comment: @Winther I'm not familiar with that. Could you explain further?

Comment: Take $x=\frac{\pi}{k}$ then the formula $P_{2k} = \frac{2p_kP_k}{p_k+P_k}$ just says that $\tan(x/2) = \frac{\sin(x)\tan(x)}{\sin(x)+\tan(x)}$. Simplifying the right hand side you get that this is just the [tangent half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula). If you have not seen this before you should probably try to derive it (see the link above for how to do this).